# How to tie up multiple objects with a rope simulation?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, shrinkwrap

Does anyone know if it is possible in Blender to tie multiple objects together with a rope by using simulation?

The goal is to have the blue objects floating until the red rope wraps around them and ties them together. Preferably without the rope getting all messed up. Maybe by using pressure in the Cloths tab?

Another important factor is that instead of the boxes in the example image a complex split up mesh (600000 verts) will be used.

My attempts:

I already tried multiple options with cloth, rigid body and soft body dynamics. To get the objects floating I turned off gravity in the scene properties.

1. The first step was to try rigid body dynamics on a reduced (low poly) mesh and then apply mesh deform on the high poly object to bind it to the low poly version with physics. This absolutely didn't work because the mesh deform doesn't recognize a rigid body moving as a mesh deformation.
2. The second attempt was to use soft body physics on all objects. This also didn't quite work as shown in the attached image.
3. Using cloth on all objects. (Had to convert the curve to a mesh). This didn't work since the red rope couldn't be scaled anymore and therefore wasn't able to wrap around the blue boxes.

I also fiddled around with the parameters and some other combinations but it won't work anyway. So does anyone have an idea or solution to this? I'd appreciate it very much.[image]

Comment: Hello, don't you want to fake physics instead of trying to use it?

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to do it. If it is actually possible with a simulation approach would still be interesting. Especially in regard to multiple objects interacting with each other.